# How to display image on Android device using QT?

Tags: android, qt, opencv

I'm trying to create an Android application using QT where I load image from the device and display it on the application.

I can create an application and load it to an Android device, and I can also successfully import OpenCV.

1. I'm having problem loading image file using:

```
QFile::exists("PATH_TO_FILE");
QImage image("PATH_TO_FILE");
```

QFile::exists says that the file I'm trying to load exists. However, when I try to load the image, my image is null.
I've tried loading an image from both internal and external memory with the following permission added to my AndroidManifest.xml: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

2. I want to load image from the device camera and display it on the widget. I can compile the application with OpenCV. However, when I tried to get image by:

```
VideoCapture vid;
vid.open(0);
Mat img;
vid >> img;
```

I get image of size 0. I did added permission android.permission.CAMERA to my AndroidManifest.xml.

Can someone please help me out? I'm not sure what I'm missing and why I'm getting null images from both files and cameras.

Any help would be appreciated

Sincerely,

Steve

Comment: On an Android 10 device? Please give examples of the used paths.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on an Android 10 device. The path used is: "/storage/emulated/0/1.jpg". I've also tried "file:///storage/emulated/0/1.jpg" without success.

Comment: How did you put that jpg file there?

Comment: I downloaded an image on an Android device, and use Android file manager app to rename and place the image

Comment: You are not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398877/read-text-file-from-download-folder-failed